# Adding controls to scrollable panel during scrolling destroys grid

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to fill `scrollable panel` with pic boxes via loop & calculacting coordinates to draw nice grid, but when I start scrolling during drawing (Im drawing e.g 50 elements with 500ms delay between each), then it becomes mess, but I'm not sure how to operate on "coordinates inside panel"

When I'm not scrolling, then everything is fine like that:

[image]

But when I start scrolling then it behaves like that:

[image]

Here's my code for Drawing each element:

```
public int X { get; set; } = 0;
public int Y { get; set; } = 200;

private void DrawImage(Image image)
{
    var height = 100;             // height of row
    var width = panel1.Width / 5; // 5 elements per row

    var picbox = new PictureBox();
    picbox.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    picbox.Name = $"image{_images.Count}";
    picbox.Image = image.Bitmap;
    picbox.Height = height;
    picbox.Width = width;

    panel1.Controls.Add(picbox);

    X += width;

    if (X >= panel1.Width)
    {
        Y += height;
        X = 0;
    }
}
```

When I performed:

> this.panel1.Controls.Cast < Control >().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("image")).Select(x => x.Location).ToList()

then I noticed that after scrolling the coordinates of "images above" changed to negative:

[image]

So, how can I can operate on coordinates inside panel, not screen?

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel or a FlowLayoutPanel. Test which one better fits your layout requirements. Maybe a ListView in LargeIcon view will also do.

Comment: As noted in the documentation `The X and Y coordinate values retrieved are negative if the control has scrolled away from its starting position (0,0)...` so the "odd" Y values are normal. For a grid, one of the  LayoutPanels might be easier and more appropriate.

Comment: "(Im drawing e.g 50 elements with 500ms delay between each)"  You're not drawing anything, you're creating new controls and adding them to the panel.  I hope you're not actually calling `var picbox = new PictureBox();`, 50 times in a loop every 500 milliseconds...

Comment: @Idle_Mind what approach would be better? I want to achieve some "loading" animation via adding new images

Comment: That layout doesn't really look like a *loading animation*. Use a GIF for that. Or paint the Bitmaps yourself. In one PictureBox.

Comment: Just add the PictureBoxes to the grid, ONCE, calculating their INITIAL positions while ignoring the scrolling aspect.  Set the [AutoScroll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll?view=netcore-3.1) property of the panel to true and you'll get scrollbars allowing you to, well, scroll.  No need to recalculate positions or anything...

Comment: @Idle_Mind that was great hint, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the PictureBoxes to the grid, ONCE, calculating their INITIAL positions while ignoring the scrolling aspect. Set the [AutoScroll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll?view=netcore-3.1) property of the panel to true and you'll get scrollbars allowing you to, well, scroll. No need to recalculate positions or anything...

@Idle_Mind that was great hint, thanks! – Axelly